# Rerunning a completed Job from Spring Framework?

Tags: spring, restlet

I am developing a web application using Spring Framework that does some jobs as the application starts up, and these jobs primarily consist of loading data from CSVs and making Java objects out of them. 
Currently, I am trying to build a RESTful API using Restlet and Spring framework and one of the queries is supposed to take in a job name as parameter and restart that job even if that job has been marked as COMPLETED, how do I accomplish a job restart? I have tried the spring frameworks' Joboperator interface's startNextInstance() method and have also tried to manually increment the JobParameters so that there is no jobinstancealrradyrunning exception?

Anyone has any code snippet or alternative idea on how to restart a Job in Spring Framework that has been marked as Completed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the terms you're using i'm quite certain you're using [Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/)

In Batch terms you cannot actually restart a COMPLETED instance or execution. Single job instance is identified by job parameters. If you need to run the job again with same parameters, one way would be to include some unique parameter, for example the current timestamp to the `JobParameters` before launching.

So *restarting* a completed job would mean **starting a new instance** of the job with similiar parameters. Here's an slightly modified snippet i've used before that uses `JobLauncher` and `JobRegistry` to launch a new job by name:

```
@Autowired 
@Qualifier("asyncJobLauncher")
private JobLauncher asyncJobLauncher;

@Autowired
private JobRegistry jobRegistry;

... 

public JobExecution startJob(String jobName) {
    Job job;
    try {
        job = jobRegistry.getJob(jobName);
    } catch (NoSuchJobException e) {
        // handle invalid job name
    }

    JobParametersBuilder jobParams = new JobParametersBuilder();
    jobParams.addLong("currentTime", System.currentTimeMillis());
    // add other relevant parameters

    try {
        JobExecution jobExecution = asyncJobLauncher.run(job, jobParams.toJobParameters());
        return jobExecution;
    } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // handle instance already running with given params 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle other errors
    }
}
```

Hope it helps, here's some [reading](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureJob.html) about the subject.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the answer. I tried the code above but unfortunately, the jobRegistry.getJob(jobName) part is throwing an exception even with a valid job name. So, am trying to see what to do about that.

Comment: What kind of exception are you seeing? Atleast you need to make sure that JobRegistry and JobLauncher components exist in the app context.

Comment: Hey, so sorry for the late reply. My JobLauncher was not correctly configured, so it wasn't running properly but I got that working now, thanks a lot for your help!